# How to find control in usercontrol from PropertyChangedCallback method?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have this code in MyControl.cs:

```
public static myMethod(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl control = d as MyControl;
    AnotherControl a = control.Findname("blabla") as AnotherControl;
}
```

The problem is that code *control.Findname("blabla")* returns null, despite that the control named "blabla" exists in my usercontrol's XAML. How to access it?

Accessing it by control.blabla is not the solution, because I have controls named blabla1, blabla2, blabla3 and I have to modify them in a loop.

EDIT: Maybe it's relevant that everything happens in WP7 environment?

Comment: Are you sure that MyControl is loaded, Check the IsLoaded property and subscribe to Loaded event if it isnt.

Comment: Well, `control` has no `IsLoaded` property, but anyway I have subscribed to Loaded event, and even then, `Findname` returns null. The control that I'm looking for definitelly exists, because I can find it while inspecting `control` variable` during debuggind session.

Comment: is the control you are looking for in the controls-collection of the user-control? or is it in a collection of a subcontrol like a panel or a group-box?

Comment: @Tomtom It's usercontrol. It's not in any kind of controls-collection. Just 20 lines of code like: `<local:AnotherControl x:Name="blabla1" Content="cont" />`

Comment: Have you tried x:FieldModifier="Public" property?

Comment: Modifying *controls* in a loop is a sign that your design is bad...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got my answer:
http://abubakar-dar.blogspot.com/2010/09/find-control-inside-silverlight.html